# How to resolve specialisation after instantiation issue?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, template-instantiation

In my code I'd like to make unordered sets with only one template parameter (if possible) like so:

```cpp
std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> my_foos;
```

The problem is that my `Foo` class also have a class member which is of the type `std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>`. Specifically my `Foo` class looks something like this:

```cpp
#include<unordered_set>
#include<memory>

class Foo {
  explicit Foo(int val) : val_(val) {}
  void AddFoo(Foo& foo){foos.insert(std::make_shared<Foo>(foo));}
  std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> foos;
  int val_;
};

namespace std {
template <>  
struct hash<shared_ptr<Foo>> {
  size_t operator()(const Foo shared_ptr<Foo>& foo) const {
    return hash<int>()(foo->val_);
  }
};

template <>
struct equal_to<Foo> {
  bool operator()(const Foo shared_ptr<Foo>& lhs, const Foo shared_ptr<Foo>& rhs) const {
    return lhs->val_ == rhs->val_;
  }
};
}
```

This gives the error

```
error: specialization of 'std::hash<std::shared_ptr<Foo> >' after instantiation
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: "I'd like to make unordered sets with only one template parameter" Any particular reason for that? Why not `using FooSet = std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, Compare>`?

Comment: `const Foo &shared_ptr<Foo> foo` whats that? Please make sure the code you post reproduces the error you ask about and not other errors

Comment: @Caleth only laziness when typing

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai woops, nice catch. My apologies. Fixing it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got your code to compile. Had to add forward declarations, separate definition from declaration (otherwise it couldn't find `Foo`'s members) for those structs, added `public` access specifier in `Foo`. Also, there was some code to cleanup in the function signatures.

```
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_set>

class Foo;  // forward declaration of Foo here

namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<shared_ptr<Foo>> {
    size_t operator()(const shared_ptr<Foo>& foo) const;
};

template <>
struct equal_to<Foo> {
    bool operator()(const shared_ptr<Foo>& lhs,
                    const shared_ptr<Foo>& rhs) const;
};
}  // namespace std

class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo(int val) : val_(val) {}
    void AddFoo(Foo& foo) { foos.insert(std::make_shared<Foo>(foo)); }
    std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> foos;
    int val_;
};

size_t std::hash<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>::operator()(
    const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& foo) const {
    return std::hash<int>()(foo->val_);
}

bool std::equal_to<Foo>::operator()(const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& lhs,
                                    const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& rhs) const {
    return lhs->val_ == rhs->val_;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solve my problem. I also had to add `inline` to the operator definitions in order not to violate ODR in my header file.